# Как удалить анимацию блока?

Tags: php, javascript, css

Как удалить анимацию родителя? animation: none у элементов не помогает.

```
<div id="some" class="main" style="background-image: 
url(/upload/test.png);animation:colors 3s infinite;">
  <a href="/folder/" class="main-list-item-title">Folder</a>
  <ul class="main-list-item-links">
    <li><a id="bx_1847241719_18" href="/folder/add/">ADDITIONAL</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: А как вы прописываете animation:none?

Comment: Да, но тогда не работает hover background-size:105% и отображается немного иначе сам блок.

Comment: background-size поправил. а отображаться, естественно, будет по другому, потмоу что у меня остальных стилей нет в примере. только для этих блоко

Comment: да, спасибо. осталось только здесь какая-то нестыковка по стилям с border-radius или background-size. в левом блоке (оригинале) как и должно быть, в правом (обновленном) отличается. вот скрин http://prntscr.com/fyxmjc (инверсию применил для удобства)

Comment: ну так примените border-radius к новому блоку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
/*var div = document.getElementsByClassName('main');
for (var i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
  div[i].style.animation = 'none';
}*/
```

```css
.main-catalog-list-item {
  height: 293px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 26px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.main-catalog-list-item-bg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-transition: all ease-out 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all ease-out 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all ease-out 0.3s;
  transition: all ease-out 0.3s;
}

.main-catalog-list-item:hover .main-catalog-list-item-bg {
  background-size: 105%;
}

a.main-catalog-list-item-title {
  font-size: 33.27px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 48px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #76b900;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0px 12px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 156px;
}

ul.main-catalog-list-item-links {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 17px;
}

ul.main-catalog-list-item-links li:after {
  content: none;
}

ul.main-catalog-list-item-links li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul.main-catalog-list-item-links li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 10px;
  /* margin-right:5px;*/
}

ul.main-catalog-list-item-links li a:hover {
  color: #76b900;
}

@keyframes colorrun {
  from {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
    filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(359deg);
    filter: hue-rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="bx_1847241719_17" class="main-catalog-list-item">
  <div class="main-catalog-list-item-bg" style="background-image: url(https://armoskill.ru/upload/iblock/89d/wallpaper_art_pc_wst_for_site_small.jpg);animation:colorrun 3s infinite;"></div>
  <a href="/catalog/rabochie-stantsii/" class="main-catalog-list-item-title">Рабочие станции</a>
  <ul class="main-catalog-list-item-links">
    <li><a id="bx_1847241719_23" href="/catalog/rabochie-stantsii/bazovye/">БАЗОВЫЕ</a></li>
    <li><a id="bx_1847241719_24" href="/catalog/rabochie-stantsii/proizvoditelnye/">ПРОИЗВОДИТЕЛЬНЫЕ</a></li>
    <li><a id="bx_1847241719_25" href="/catalog/rabochie-stantsii/multimediynye/">МУЛЬТИМЕДИЙНЫЕ</a></li>
    <li><a id="bx_1847241719_26" href="/catalog/rabochie-stantsii/spetsializirovannye/">СПЕЦИАЛИЗИРОВАННЫЕ</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: А без кнопок? Просто чтобы дальше не наследовалась анимация родителя. Я дилетант в JS, как это внедрить конкретно в шаблон сайта (по принципу copy&past)?

Comment: @Юрий посмотрите обновленный ответ. Я вывел картинку в отдельный div.main-catalog-list-item-bg. Теперь вам нужно найтив в шаблоне место, где выводятся эти блоки и немного подкорректировать структуру в соответствии с моим ответом

Comment: @Юрий получилось?

Comment: Завтра буду пробовать, потом отпишусь)

Comment: спасибо, что помогли. все получилось)

Comment: готово, отметил.